# Quartz.NET Daily Time Interval across midnight

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I have the following configuration settings in my domain model for my scheduled tasks and I am trying to create triggers using Quartz.NET 2.3.3.

1. Start Time `TimeSpan`
2. End Time `TimeSpan`
3. Repeat Interval `TimeSpan`
4. Weekdays Enabled `DayOfWeek[]`

I can successfully create a Daily Time Interval Trigger with this information.

```
var trigger = TriggerBuilder
    .Create()
    .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(c => c
        .StartingDailyAt(scheduledTask.StartTime.ToTimeOfDay())
        .EndingDailyAt(scheduledTask.EndTime?.ToTimeOfDay())
        .OnDaysOfTheWeek(scheduledTask.WeekdaysEnabled.ToDaysOfWeek().ToArray())
        .WithIntervalInSeconds((int)scheduledTask.RepeatInterval.TotalSeconds)
        .InTimeZone(timeZoneInfo))
    .Build();
```

It is, however, possible for my configured EndTime to be *before* the StartTime. For example, 22:30 to 04:00 (running from 10:30 PM until 4:00 AM the following day, repeating at the specified interval, across the midnight boundary). The Daily Time Interval Schedule does not seem to support this. It only fires once, at the start time, and never again.

I have tried using a `CronTrigger`, as this works across the midnight boundary, but this doesn't support the start/end time of day properly (eg. `0 30-0/30 22-4 ? * *` runs every 30 mins from 10:00 PM until 4:30 AM.

Is there any way to create this schedule within Quartz.NET?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to get around this problem by creating two Daily Time Interval Triggers. One trigger has a start time of 10:30 PM and no end time (runs until the end of the day). The other trigger has no start time but an end time of 4:00 AM.

Scheduling a job with both of these triggers produces the desired firing times.

```
1/01/2015 10:30:00 PM
1/01/2015 11:00:00 PM
1/01/2015 11:30:00 PM
2/01/2015 12:00:00 AM
2/01/2015 12:30:00 AM
2/01/2015 1:00:00 AM
2/01/2015 1:30:00 AM
2/01/2015 2:00:00 AM
2/01/2015 2:30:00 AM
2/01/2015 3:00:00 AM
2/01/2015 3:30:00 AM
2/01/2015 4:00:00 AM
2/01/2015 10:30:00 PM
2/01/2015 11:00:00 PM
2/01/2015 11:30:00 PM
3/01/2015 12:00:00 AM
3/01/2015 12:30:00 AM
3/01/2015 1:00:00 AM
3/01/2015 1:30:00 AM
3/01/2015 2:00:00 AM
3/01/2015 2:30:00 AM
3/01/2015 3:00:00 AM
3/01/2015 3:30:00 AM
3/01/2015 4:00:00 AM
```